# Split multi-month records into individual months

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, recursive-query

I have data in a table in this format - where date range is multi-month:

```
SourceSink  Class   ShadowPrice Round   Period  StartDate   EndDate
 AEC        Peak    447.038      3     WIN2020  2020-12-01  2021-02-28
```

I want to create a view/ insert into a new table - the above record broken by month as shown below:

```
SourceSink  Class   ShadowPrice Round   Period  StartDate   EndDate
 AEC        Peak    447.038      3     WIN2020  2020-12-01  2021-12-31
 AEC        Peak    447.038      3     WIN2020  2021-01-01  2021-01-31
 AEC        Peak    447.038      3     WIN2020  2021-02-01  2021-02-28
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Create a table of calendar months. Join against condition does month overlap with start and end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option using a `CROSS APPLY` and an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Select A.[SourceSink]
      ,A.[Class]
      ,A.[ShadowPrice]
      ,A.[Round]
      ,A.[Period]
      ,B.[StartDate]
      ,B.[EndDate]
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select StartDate=min(D)
                      ,EndDate  =max(D)
                  From (
                         Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[StartDate],[EndDate])+1) 
                                D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[StartDate]) 
                          From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
                       ) B1
                  Group By Year(D),Month(D)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option is a recursive query. Assuming that periods always start on the the first day of a month and end on the last day of a month, as shown in your sample data, that would be:

```
with cte as (
    select t.*, startDate newStartDate, eomonth(startDate) newEndDate
    from mytable t
    union all
    select 
        sourceSink,
        class,
        shadowPrice,
        period,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        dateadd(month, 1, newStartDate),
        eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, newStartDate))
    from cte
    where newStartDate < endDate
)
select * from cte
```

If periods start and end on variying month days, then we need a little more logic:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        t.*, 
        startDate newStartDate, 
        case when eomonth(startDate) <= endDate then eomonth(startDate) else endDate end newEndDate
    from mytable t
    union all
    select 
        sourceSink,
        class,
        shadowPrice,
        period,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(newStartDate), month(newStartDate), 1)),
        case when eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(newStartDate), month(newStartDate), 1))) <= endDate
            then eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(newStartDate), month(newStartDate), 1)))
            else endDate
        end
    from cte
    where datefromparts(year(newStartDate), month(newStartDate), 1) < endDate
)
select * from cte
```